# MIPS recursion: How to compute end result from stack

Tags: assembly, recursion, mips

My task is to implement egyptian multiplication in MIPS assembler recursively.
I think I understood most of the relevant stuff, but I just can't get behind one thing:
How is the end result computed?
For example in this code(taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222861/recursion-in-mips) question):

```
# int fact(int n)
fact:
subu    sp, sp, 32  # Allocate a 32-byte stack frame
sw  ra, 20(sp)  # Save Return Address
sw  fp, 16(sp)  # Save old frame pointer
addiu   fp, sp, 28  # Setup new frame pointer
sw  a0,  0(fp)  # Save argument (n) to stack

lw  v0, 0(fp)   # Load n into v0
bgtz    v0, L2      # if n > 0 jump to rest of the function
li  v0, 1       # n==1, return 1
j   L1      # jump to frame clean-up code

L2:
lw  v1, 0(fp)   # Load n into v1
subu    v0, v1, 1   # Compute n-1
move    a0, v0      # Move n-1 into first argument
jal fact        # Recursive call

lw  v1, 0(fp)   # Load n into v1
mul v0, v0, v1  # Compute fact(n-1) * n

#Result is in v0, so clean up the stack and return
L1:
lw  ra, 20(sp)  # Restore return address
lw  fp, 16(sp)  # Restore frame pointer
addiu   sp, sp, 32  # Pop stack
jr  ra      # return
.end    fact
```

How/ when are the two lines between

```
jal fact
```

and

```
L2
```

ever reached? In my understanding, either L1/L2 are branched to, or fact is called recursively...

---

/Edit:

Ok, it seems that I figured out how to implement something recursively in MIPS. However, I have one last problem: With the code below, my program lacks one "turn", meaning that the last value isn't considered when computing the final result.

```
pharao:
    li $t0, 2       #load imm for division by 2
    lw $a0, fac_1       #load fac_1 into $a0
    lw $a1, fac_2       #load fac_2 into $a1
    li $t7, 0       #zero $t7
    li $t6, 1       #load 1 into $t6

    jal egypt       #jump to egypt
    j end




egypt:      
    subiu $sp,$sp,16    #space on stack for 4 values
    sw $ra,0($sp)       #store return address
    sw $a0, 4($sp)      #store fac_1
    sw $a1, 8($sp)      #store fac_2
    divu $a1, $t0       #div fac_2 by 2
    mflo $a1        #store quotient in $a1
    mfhi $a2        #store remainder in $a2
    sw $a2, 12($sp)     #store remainder on stack


    multu $a0, $t0      #multiply fac_1 by 2
    mflo $a0

    beq $a1, $t6, return    #base case

    jal egypt       #call egypt recursively

addingup:       
    lw $a0, 4($sp)      #load values from stack
    lw $a1, 8($sp)      #   "
    lw $a2, 12($sp)     #   "

    beqz $a2, return    #jump on if remainder is 0

    addu $t7, $t7, $a0  #add if remainder is 1      
return:     

    lw $ra, 0($sp)      #restore return address
    addiu $sp, $sp, 16  #inc stackpointer
    jr $ra
```

When I try running the program with the values 10 and 20, the result (in $t7) is 40, because the last value, 160, isn't added. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`jal` is the instruction `JUMP AND LINK`, which means it stores the next instruction's address in r31 and jumps to the label given. You could say it's (one/the) way to do subroutine calls in MIPS assembler.

The `jr $ra` jumps to the address contained in r31, which means it returns to the instruction following `jal`. As you can see, that's done just before the `.end`.

In short, `jal` is a subroutine call, and when the call *returns*, it will execute the instructions following `jal`.

In your edited question, you check the base case a bit strangely, something like;

```
a = n >> 1;
b = n & 1;
if(a == 0)
   return 0;
...do calculation...
```

...when a much better base case would be;

```
if(n == 0)
   return 0;
a = n >> 1;
b = n & 1;
...do calculation...
```

The problem with the first base case is that b can still be 1 and give a result, but you return anyway without using the value.

Comment: Ok, and this is done as often as the function has been called recursively?

Comment: Yes, for each call there will be a return in this case. One thing to pay attention to when programming MIPS assembler is the delay slots, the next instruction may be executed _before_ the branch/call is taken. I can't remember if the assemblers rearrange that or not for you automatically, it's been probably 20 years since I programmed MIPS assembler... :)

Comment: @PeterPanter Added some info on your edit, although it should probably have been a new question instead of an edit when the scope changes that much.